# How to set different views dynamically in getView() of adapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am creating a submit form by getting data from server, this form may have different views (`EditText`, `CheckBox`, `RadioButton`, `RatingBar`) according what the server suggest. I have successfully created that view in adapter but every time I scroll down or up the user's answer get cleared (like checked Item get unchecked automatically, `EditText` get cleared etc) and also the views get automatically exchanged their position from first to last or just get swapped. I don't know how to solve that, here is my `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customratinglist, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvQuestion = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtquestion);
        holder.tvQuestion.setTag(list.get(position));
        holder.layOut = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lnQuestion);
        holder.layOut.setTag(position);
        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        rowView = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).layOut.setTag(position);
    }
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    viewHolder.tvQuestion.setTypeface(font);
    viewHolder.tvQuestion.setText(list.get(position).getQuestion());
    viewHolder.layOut.removeAllViews();
    switch (list.get(position).getAns_type_id()) {
        case "1":
            ratingBar = new RatingBar(context);
            ratingBar.setNumStars(5);
            ratingBar.setStepSize(0.1f);
            ratingBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            viewHolder.layOut.addView(ratingBar);

            ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {


                    answerSetter((int) (viewHolder.layOut.getTag()), String.valueOf(rating));
                }
            });

            break;


        case "2":

            editText = new EditText(context);
            editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            viewHolder.layOut.addView(editText);

            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                    answerSetter((int) (viewHolder.layOut.getTag()), String.valueOf(s));
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            break;
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a using these two methods :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getAns_type_id());
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

After that you can use `getItemViewType` method inside of `getView` method with `position` which is passed as param in `getView` method.

For more info please take a look for this [tutorial](http://learnncode.co/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) is documentation for these methods.

Comment: viewType is not always the same in my case, It may have two or three or more type, so I dont know when the server gives how many answer type

Comment: yout tutorial link is not available too

Comment: But you know how many different types it can be. You don't have use all types

Answer (score 0):

u can try like this,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View row;


        switch (Maintain_List.get(position))
        {
            case 1:
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);


                TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
                tv.setText("" + sliding_menu_text.get(position));


                ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
                iv1.setImageResource(sliding_menu_icon.get(position));
                break;

            case 2:
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);
                break;

            case 3:


                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row3, parent, false);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_of_row3);
                tv2.setText("" + sliding_menu_text.get(position));


                break;

            case 4:

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_category, parent, false);


                final Button b = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn_of_refresh_category);
                final WebView wv = (WebView) row.findViewById(R.id.wv_of_refresh_category);
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        NetworkCheck nc = new NetworkCheck(getActivity());
                        isInternetPresent = nc.isConnectingToInternet();
                        if (!isInternetPresent)
                        {
                            // Ntwork not avilabale
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Error !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Ntwork Avilable
                            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/m.html");
                            wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            new get_List_of_Drawer().execute();


                        }


                    }
                });

                break;


            default:
                row = null;
                break;

        }


        return row;

    }
```

works fine for me...!!!